# Pandas Dataframe replace part of string with value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace

I having replace issue while I try to replace a string with value from another column.
I want to replace 'Length' with df['Length'].

```
df["Length"]= df["Length"].replace('Length', df['Length'], regex = True)
```

Below is my data

```
Input:
**Formula**  **Length**
Length           5
Length+1.5       6
Length-2.5       5
Length           4
5                5

Expected Output:
**Formula**  **Length**
5                5
6+1.5            6
5-2.5            5
4                4
5                5
```

However, with the code I used above, it will replace my entire cell instead of Length only.
I getting below output:
I found it was due to df['column'] is used, if I used any other string the behind offset (-1.5) will not get replaced.

```
**Formula**  **Length**
5                5
6                6
5                5
4                4
5                5
```

May I know is there any replace method for values from other columns?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If want replace by another column is necessary use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df["Formula"]= df.apply(lambda x: x['Formula'].replace('Length', str(x['Length'])), axis=1)
print (df)
  Formula  Length
0       5       5
1   6+1.5       6
2   5-2.5       5
3       4       4
4       5       5
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df["Formula"]= [x.replace('Length', str(y)) for x, y  in df[['Formula','Length']].to_numpy()]
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael :) It is working good! Thanks for introduce .apply with me and also the alternative solution. I am really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, that list comprehension is much faster of course:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aba'] * 1000000, 'c': ['c'] * 1000000})

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['a'].replace('b', x['c']), axis=1)
# 1 loop, best of 5: 11.8 s per loop

%timeit [x.replace('b', str(y)) for x, y in df[['a', 'c']].to_numpy()]
# 1 loop, best of 5: 1.3 s per loop
```